# Absolute frequencies (xtabs) to relative frequencies with apply?

Tags: r

I needed to get absolute frequencies for multiple variable pairs in my dataset, so I used this code to "loop" the `xtabs` command:

```
apply(table[,2:17], 2, function(x) xtabs(~tablel$variable+x))
```

It worked fine and gave me the absolute frequencies by the variable. However, I now need to get relative frequencies from these by the row and I can't figure out how.

Can I somehow include the relative frequency calculation in the loop already? Or do I have to create a new dataset for that (and how? I can't seem to get the absolute frequencies out of R).

Here's an example of one of the variable's frequencies I got with the code.

```
$SEM
          x
       MN          sem1       sem2        sem3
       N1          227        130          18
       N10           0          2           7
       N11           9          7           5
       N12          29         21           1
       N2           23         14           2
       N3           19          7           4
       N4           12         17           0
       N5           18         36           3
       N6           22         13           7
       N8            1         39           0
       N9            0          2           5
```

Comment: `t(apply(SEM, 1, function(i) i/sum(i)))` ?

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't get that to work exactly but I get what you mean. However, that would calculate the frequencies within that one variable $SEM, but I have 16 of these small "tables", I was wondering if I could combine all of them for calculating the frequencies.

Comment: do you have your tables in a list?

Comment: Yes, it's a list of 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply a function through the list. Assuming the list with your 16 data frames is called `lst` then,

```
lapply(lst, function(i) t(apply(i[,-1], 1, function(j) j/sum(j))))
```

Comment: It worked! I modified it a bit so the code that solved the problem was
    lapply(x, function(i) t(apply(i[drop=F], 1, function(j) j/sum(j)))) . Thanks a lot!